# Doing SUM operation with JPA

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In DB, I have '(Number of) `ID`' column and '`Date`' column having date format as D`D:MM:YYYYTHH:MM:SS`.

For e.g.

```
ID Date
5 12.07.2020T11:11:43

7 11.06.2020T15:14:45

8 12.07.2020T11:14:45

6 11.06.2020T14:14:45
```

Using JPA (with Spring boot in Java), I want to calculate the SUM of particular items for a single day.(e.g. sum of items for single day for 12:07:2020 ( 5 + 8) and for 11.06.2020 (7 + 6). Can I do SUM operation for single day in this case?

Regards, Stephan

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, by using a native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT sum(Id),Date FROM IdDateS WHERE u.date = ?1 GROUP BY Date", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Collection<IdDate> findSumOfIdOnSpecificDay(Timestamp date);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I am not so expert in JPA. My working scenario is that i fetch rows which has timestamp between given interval. e.g. List<Rows> findByDateTimeBefore(Date to); For these rows (List<Rows>), i want to do above calculation i.e. sum(Id) for single day. With above code, it does not work. Can you guide me further ?